# How to use ggplot function for a lot of data frame at once?

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I loaded a lot of .xls files as separate data frames to my global environment and now I would like to make graphs ( and use ggplot function ) Can I use to do it "loop for" ? How to write this code correct? I tried something like this:

```
files <- list.files("path", pattern = "xls?$", full.names = T)
list <- lapply(files, read_excel)

for (i in 1:length(list))
assign(paste(paste("file", i, sep=""), "df", sep="."), list[[i]])
assign(melt(list[[i]], id.vars="Cele"), list[[i]])
list[[i]]<-ggplot(list[[i]], aes(x=variable,y=value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
ggsave(list[[i]],filename=paste("myplot",i,".png",sep=""))
```

Could someone help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
l <- list(mtcars,mtcars[1:15,],mtcars[16:32,])
plot_list <- vector("list",length(l))

p <- ggplot(data = l[[1]],aes(x = mpg,y = disp)) + geom_point()

for (i in seq_along(l)){
    plot_list[[i]] <- p %+% l[[i]]
}
```

You made a good choice to use `lapply` and `list.files` to read in the data into a single object, a list. After that, you took a step backwards by using `assign` to remove them from a nice convenient list into separate objects. Try to avoid `assign` until you have a good sense for when it's really necessary.

I used a slightly unnecessary trick, `%+%`, just to illustrate something useful. It allows to take an existing plot and throw different data frames at it. It can sometimes save you from writing repeated `ggplot` code.

Comment: I have error: "could not find function "%+%"" . What can I do?? Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Then you haven't loaded ggplot, which would be necessary to do anything in ggplot I would think.